# Yii 2.0 timestamp wrong showing 01/01/1970 03:33

Tags: php, time, yii2

So im using Yii 2.0 TimestampBehavior but it shows me wrong dates, created date allways is 01/01/1970 03:33 and update date 01/01/1970 03:00

```
public function behaviors()
{
return [
    'timestamp' => [
        'class' => TimestampBehavior::className(),
        'attributes' => [
            ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => 'create_time',
            ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'update_time',
        ],
        'value' => new Expression('NOW()'),
    ],
];
}
```

SQL Schema defintion is

```
'id' => 'INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT',
'title' => 'VARCHAR(255)',
'data' => 'TEXT',
'create_time' => 'INT',
'update_time' => 'INT'
```

Comment: what is your SQL table definition?

Comment: 'id' => 'INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT',
        'title' => 'VARCHAR(255)',
        'data' => 'TEXT',
        'create_time' => 'INT',
        'update_time' => 'INT'

Answer (score 2):

If you define your date columns as INT you can not use `NOW()` to set them because `NOW()` returns a value of type "date". You can either define your columns as [DATETIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/datetime.html) and keep the PHP code as is or use the PHP function `time()` for getting the date value. This is the [default behavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-behaviors-timestampbehavior.html#%24value-detail), so simply do not specify 'value' in the behavior configuration:

```
'timestamp' => [
    'class' => \yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior::className(),
    'attributes' => [
        ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_INSERT => 'create_time',
        ActiveRecord::EVENT_BEFORE_UPDATE => 'update_time',
    ],
],
```

Comment: Or change the DbExpression to 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP()' :)